# Generating action link with noCacheHash=true argument not working as expected

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-9.x

Typo3 **v9.5.5**, PHP **7.2**, after upgrade from 8.7. Cache cleared, cache turned off, Development environment. My extension has **`requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments`** set 0.

I generate links to actions using syntax as below:

**`<f:link.action action="test" noCacheHash="1"></f:link.action>`**

Unfortunately, **`cHash`** argument **is always present** in returned URL. It breaks my extension's logic, as I add extra attributes to URL in my JavaScript code before calling action via ajax request.

**I expected `noCacheHash` argument to cause removal of `cHash` argument from URL.**

**I expected setting `requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments` prevent any URL validation problems even if `cHash` is present in URL.**

I am aware of `cHashExcludedParameters` config setting, but **I would like to turn off `cHash` for my extension generally**.

So, I am asking for help or explanation.

**Edit:** if I remove `chash` argument manualy from URL and call it, request is processed with success. So, it means, `requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments` is processed fine, but only when `chash` is not present in URL.

**Edit 2:**

In my case invalid cHash caused `pageNotFoundOnCHashError` handler being called. I set `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError'] = false;` in `AdditionalConfiguration.php` and it "solved" a problem (not an elegant fix).

Comment: Actually this is already gone with v8
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78002-EnforceCHashArgumentForExtbaseActions.html

Comment: @MKlein, Documentation says it can be disabled: The behavior can be disabled for all actions using the feature switch requireCHashArgumentForActionArguments.

Comment: I can only provide one solution for your: If you fiddle with the GET params in JS already, simply kick the chash value as well and you are done.
Keep in mind: Any request that does not have a valid cHash param will not be cachable by the core, that can be a major performance topic!

Comment: I had that in mind, but it is not a elegant and flexible soultion, as I would have to always remeber of removing manualy chash, when adding new ajax request to JS app. I am aware of preformance problems without cache in Typo3. Thanks for Your comments and suggestions.

Comment: @qba-dev , Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Ques no, I didn't

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own RouteEnhancer with attributes to remove cHash in URL. Here [RoutingEnhancersAndAspects](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#staticvaluemapper) are some good examples for that.

Your `config.yaml`could look like this:

```
ProductDetail:
  type: Extbase
  limitToPages: [your_PageId]
  extension: YourExtPlaceholder
  plugin: Pi1
  routes:
   - { routePath: '/{product_title}', _controller: 'Product::detail', _arguments: {'product_title': 'product'} }
  defaultController: 'Product::detail'
  defaults:
     page: '0'
     requirements:
  page: '\d+'
  aspects:
    product_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: tx_yourext_domain_model_product
      routeFieldName: slug
```